# Jquery Autopopulate on Textarea with no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to add the auto suggest JQuery plugin to a textbox. I was able to do it with the below code in another textbox which had an 'id'. But this new textbox that I'm working on does not have an id and I guess the Class is my only option here. But I'm unable to get the auto suggest work in this textarea. Could anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong or is this not the right approach for a class.?

```js
var tCodes = ["head", "hello", "heart", "health", "horizontal"];
$('.sn-chat-textarea').autocomplete({
  source: tCodes
}, {
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<textarea class="sn-chat-textarea" rows="1" placeholder="Type a message" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" role="combobox" value="" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 40px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: I've placed your code in a snippet, along with the required libraries, where it works absolutely fine. Check you've included both jQuery AND jQuery UI, and both in the correct order. Also check the console for errors elsewhere in your codebase which may prevent this from working.

Comment: its functional no error

Comment: I have the JQuery and UI both in my code. As I said it works fine in another textbox but not this one. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I do not get any error in console. I tried to get the value of this textbox using setInterval() method, I get undefined.

Comment: sorry i dont understanf what you mean, the autosuggest is functional with this textarea which has just class selector.. the problem is not the sample you have displayed.

Comment: Yes the problem seems to be somewhere else. This is a chat window with a textbox to enter the question. I was trying to add autosuggest option to this textbox. Looks like the page does not allow it.